# The Plot $K=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :Re(z)\geq 0 \text{ and } Im(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Im sorry, I'm confused.

The Plot $K=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :Re(z)\geq 0 \text{ and } Im(z)>0\}$, in the follow-up book this
[image]

Why?

I'm confused.

I think I should take the y-axis and leave the x-axis dotted..

Answer (score 0):

If we define $z=x+iy$, then $\Re(z)=x$ and $\Im(z)=y$ so the inequalities become:

$$x\ge0, y\gt0$$

which means you are right and your book is wrong.